# NameError: name 'cap' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have defined **cap** in

```
def fingerCursor(device):
    global cap
    global cap_height
    global cap_width
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
        #cap.set(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720)
        #cap.set(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        #print(cap_height,cap_width)
```

But still whenever I am running this part of my code, it says **cap** not defined. It also has the same problem with **cap_height** and **cap_width**.

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
        ## capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame_raw = cap.read()
        while not ret:
            ret,frame_raw = cap.read()
        frame_raw = cv2.flip(frame_raw, 1)
        frame = frame_raw[:round(cap_height),:round(cap_width)] # ROI of the image
        cv2.imshow("raw_frame",frame)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variables have to be defined outside of your function. And you have to keep your lines starting with `global` to declare you want to modify those variables outside of your function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not create the variables in the global scope. And anyway, it is generally a bad idea to use `global` this way. I suggest changing your function to:

```
def fingerCursor(device):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
    cap_height = cap.get(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    cap_width = cap.get(cv2.cap_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    return (cap, cap_height, cap_width)
```

and then using it like this:

```
cap, cap_height, cap_width = fingerCursor(whatever)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping me out, I tried to change my code with that of yours but now there has been a new error generating

Comment: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cap_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT'